# QuickFix/N sending error message before getting to crack

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to subscribe to MarketData SnapShot full refresh.

I can see data message 35=W coming in from an established API, but I
cannot catch it in either FromApp or FromAdmin.

The quick fix engine is immediately finding something wrong with the
message (repeat tags) and is sending an automatic error message to API
via ToAdmin, But I suspect message is OK, it is just the engine
doesn't like it.

It never gets chance to get cracked. Why is this happening?

```
My subscription message:
 8=FIX.4.4|9=130|35=V|34=2|49=STR.NY.SIM|52=20150429-10:52:21.032|56=XXX|262=MARKETDATAID|263=1|264=1|265=0|267=1|269=0|146=1|55=EUR/USD|10=114|

Reply from API:
 8=FIX.4.4|9=0342|35=W|49=XXX|56=STR.NY.SIM|52=20150429-10:52:21.035|34=2|262=MARKETDATAID|55=EUR/USD|64=SP|268=2|269=0|278=2ba#1430304740070#0.B_J0+|270=1.39076|271=4000000|272=20150429|273=10:52:20.070|15=EUR|282=JPMC|64=20150501|269=1|278=2ba#1430304740070#0.O_J0+|270=1.39088|271=4000000|272=20150429|273=10:52:20.070|15=EUR|282=JPMC|64=20150501|10=080|

QuickFix response BEFORE crack:
 8=FIX.4.4|9=121|35=3|34=3|49=STR.NY.SIM|52=20150429-10:52:21.108|56=XXX|45=2|58=Tag appears more than once|371=64|372=W|373=13|10=221|
```

Comment: It's hard to analyze the FIX messages with the delimeters removed. Try replace the delimeter (SOH) with | symbol.

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that - gets lost when I copy and paste...

Comment: @TT fixed the delimeters

Comment: "Engine doesn't like it" typically means you've configured QuickFix for a FIX version earlier than the one used in the message. Which version did you specify in the configuration files? Which data dictionary?

Comment: Yes. It appears my FIX4.4 dictionary is slightly different to API 4.4 dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see field `64` mentioned in the definition of [MarketData SnapShot full refresh message for FIX4.4](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.4/body_514887.html). Not just that, it appears more than once in the reply from the "established" API.

Field `64` is the field for [Settlement Date](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.4/tag64.html)... It may be that the counterparty is sending more data than is required or interprets this as another field. Even so, the format of the contents should be `YYYYMMDD` which is not so for the first occurrence of this field.

QuickFIX validates messages according to the Data Dictionary (cf FIX4.4.xml). If this field does not appear in the specification the message will be rejected by QuickFIX.

If the counterparty cannot change this, ie will keep sending tag 64 in message type W, you will have to either tweak the data dictionary specifically for this counterparty, or try find a way to remove the tags before processing this message.

EDIT: I did find an occurrence of [tag 64 in the FIX 5.0 SP2 specification](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.5.0SP2/body_514887.html)... Your counterparty is responding with fields from another fix version.

Comment: Looks like counterparty has a custom FIX4.4 dictionary

Comment: @ManInMoon It appears so, or even yet they are using the FIX 5.0 specification to respond as I indicated in the EDIT. Perhaps you could use the message specification from FIX5.0.xml and use it in your custom FIX4.4.xml